# How does the automated 'Ask Question' Ban work?

Tags: support, post-ban

How does the automated system that bans you from asking questions work and why can a moderator not lift that ban? Are there actually statistics that you must reach to lift the ban?

The message that is displayed when you try to ask a question when you have a question ban:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the
>   Help Center to learn more.

I am not asking how I lift the ban , I am asking how the system and algorithm works and does its calculations. I couldn't find the information and was intrigued.

Comment: Well, you keep insisting that this is not a duplicate, flagging your question, etc.  What do you hope to achieve?  That we post an actual answer that says the information is proprietary? Oh, wait.  [That already happened](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263010/102937).

Comment: I have to say that it is a pathetic system!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm is not disclosed to avoid easy gaming of the system.

It is entirely automated - there is no way to lift it directly. Not by developers, employees or moderators.

Comment: Although we now offer [parole](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/102937).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - kinda, I guess

Comment: On the help page it states... "The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received." Are there actualy solid statistics in the system that define when a users contributions outweigh the negatives? Or is it random?

Comment: @AlexHarvey - yes, there are solid statistics. No, it is not random, not by a long shot.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not believe this is a duplicate as I am not asking how to release the ban I am asking how the system and algorithm works and does its calculation.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: That information is proprietary.  The linked question is the only publicly information avaiable about the question ban.